# Updating UITableView's numberOfRowsInSection after async call

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that needs to display  messages that are downloaded (asynchronously) from the database. There might be no messages, so I'd like to display a static text saying that explicitly. The problem is that after the data is being downloaded and cached into an array, the `UILabel` placed on the `tableView.backgroundView` is still there. I'm not sure why. Here's my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!    
var messages = [Message]()
var users = [UserModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadMessages()
}

 // All of these are called Async
 func loadMessages() {
    guard let userUid = Api.Users.CURRENT_USER?.uid else { return }
    Api.Message.observeUsersMessagesForUser(withId: userUid) { messageKey in
        Api.Message.observeMessage(with: messageKey, completion: { message in
            self.fetchUsers(userId: message.to!, completion: {
                self.messages.append(message)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

func fetchUsers(userId: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    Api.Users.observeUsersShort { user in
        self.users.append(user)
        completion()
    }
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if messages.isEmpty {
        showNoDataTableView()
        return 0
    }
    else {
        return messages.count
    }
}

 func showNoDataTableView() {
  //  self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    if messages.isEmpty {
        let noDataLabel: UILabel  = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width,
                                                          height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height))
        noDataLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        noDataLabel.text = "No messages yet :( \r\n\n Don't be afraid to start a conversation."
        noDataLabel.textColor = Theme.current.label_noData_textColor
        noDataLabel.font = Theme.current.label_noData_font
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        tableView.backgroundView  = noDataLabel
        tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = Theme.current.tableView_backgroundView_backgroundColor
        tableView.separatorStyle  = .none
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't put `showNoDataTableView()` in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Just return the usual

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}
```

and put `showNoDataTableView()` in the dispatch async closure in `loadMessages()`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    showNoDataTableView()
}
```

In `showNoDataTableView()` you have to check

- Create the label if `messages` is empty and the label doesn't exist (yet).
- Remove the label if `messages` is **not** empty and the label **does** exist.

In both other cases do nothing.

```
 func showNoDataTableView() {
  //  self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    if messages.isEmpty && tableView.backgroundView == nil {
        let noDataLabel: UILabel  = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width,
                                                          height: self.tableView.bounds.size.height))
        noDataLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        noDataLabel.text = "No messages yet :( \r\n\n Don't be afraid to start a conversation."
        noDataLabel.textColor = Theme.current.label_noData_textColor
        noDataLabel.font = Theme.current.label_noData_font
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        tableView.backgroundView  = noDataLabel
        tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = Theme.current.tableView_backgroundView_backgroundColor
        tableView.separatorStyle  = .none
    } else if !messages.isEmpty && tableView.backgroundView != nil {
        tableView.backgroundView  = nil
        tableView.separatorStyle  =  // set default style
    }
}
```

Comment: One slight problem actually. If there's no data, nothing happens. It shows a blank `UITableView`. The `showNoDataTableView()` is not being called since it's only called after the async calls are completed

Comment: Two options: 1) Call `showNoDataTableView()` once in `viewDidLoad()` before loading the data. 2) Is there any indication in the API calls (or an extra API call) that there is no data? If yes check it and call `showNoDataTableView()` there.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking as well. I'm just going to modify the API call to also return a `Bool` value and based on that, I'll call the `showNoDataTableView()`. Thank you!